# List of dictionaries - subtract a constant from each dictionary value

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
list = [{'score': 93, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 32, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 39, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 81, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 82, 'numrep': 0}]
```

What would be the most efficient way to subtract constant x = 1 from each score value, so I the resulting list would be:

```
resulting_list = [{'score': 92, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 31, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 38, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 80, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 81, 'numrep': 0}]
```

Comment: Don't name your variable `list`; it shadows the built-in type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to modify the dicts in place, use a loop:

```
for d in lst:
    d['score'] -= 1
```

If you need a *copy* of all dictionaries, a list comprehension with nested dict comprehension works but may not be the most efficient:

```
[{k: v - 1 if k == 'score' else v for k, v in d.iteritems()} for d in lst]
```

Demo of the latter:

```
>>> lst = [{'score': 93, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 32, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 39, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 81, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 82, 'numrep': 0}]
>>> [{k: v - 1 if k == 'score' else v for k, v in d.iteritems()} for d in lst] 
[{'score': 92, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 31, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 38, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 80, 'numrep': 0}, {'score': 81, 'numrep': 0}]
```

A function that creates a copy of the dictionary and adjusts the score:

```
def subtract_score(d):
    d = d.copy()
    d['score'] -= 1
    return d
```

then

```
[subtract_score(d) for d in lst]
```

*may* be faster for larger dictionaries.

Comment: I am new to python so thanks for quick answer. This: for d in lst:
    d['score'] -= 1 did what I needed. Thanks!